# Need steps to implement liquibase in spring boot with docker and how to execute using docker

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-pro

Need steps to implement liquibase in spring boot application with dockerfile. And Need steps for how to execute liquibase using docker.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.liquibase.org/blog/using-liquibase-via-docker) documentation from Liquibase shows how to get a container running that contains liquibase for you to execute.

[Here](https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/springboot/using-springboot-with-maven.html) is the basics on using Liquibase with SpringBoot (and Maven)

If you run into issues you can ask directly on the [Liquibase Forum](https://forum.liquibase.org) or use Discord to [chat](https://discord.gg/9yBwMtj) directly with Liquibase users / contributors.